# Python: mock.create_autospec() does not perform argument checking for builtin functions

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Mocks obtained from [`unittest.mock.create_autospec()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec) do not seem to be performing argument checking for some functions. For example, consider the following code (I used `CPython 3.4.0`):

```
import os
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

def os_chdir(dir): # The same signature as os.chdir().
    pass

m1 = create_autospec(os_chdir)
m1('first', 'second') # Raises TypeError: too many positional arguments.

m2 = create_autospec(os.chdir)
m2('first', 'second') # Passes without an exception...
```

Why `m1` correctly checks the argument count but `m2` does not? The same situation is for other functions that identify themselves as `built-in function` when printed in an interactive session. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.mock.html) does not seem to mention such situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found, the answer probably lies in the following:

```
import inspect

print(inspect.getfullargspec(os_chdir))
# Prints FullArgSpec(args=['dir'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None,
#                    kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})

print(inspect.getfullargspec(os.chdir))
# Raises ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function chdir>
```

That is, `unittest.mock.create_autospec()` has no way of finding the signature for such built-in functions.